# sum one sql column based on two columns another table with criteria

Tags: asp.net, sql

Table `teststock`:

```
type date   time product qty
in  26-Apr  6.5 vs29    10
out 26-Apr  5.4 vs29    2
in  26-Apr  8.9 vs29    5
out 25-Apr  7.2 vs29    10
in  27-Apr  5.2 vs29    5
```

Table `product list`:

```
id  product inward  outward stock
1   vs29    20      12      8
```

I need sql statements for asp.net.

1. sum the inward in product list from qty based on type in
2. sum the outward in product list from qty based on type out
3. finally subtract inward-outward

Comment: so you want to populate `product list` with that information or is that information already there?

Comment: As usual, what have you tried?

Comment: Seems like bad design to me. Product list should just have the stock level and when test stock is added / removed, the stock level should be adjusted as part of that insert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but I think you want to do something like this :

```
select a.product , sum(a.inward) inward ,sum(a.outward) outward , sum(a.inward) - sum(a.outward) stock   from (
select product , case when type = 'in' then qty else 0 end inward , 
case when type = 'out' then qty else 0 end outward
from test_stock) a
group by a.product
```

This is sqlfiddle link about sql query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65f06e/5